# flutter - Play first visible item in the list view with the help of video player controller

Tags: flutter, listview, video-player

I am trying to implement a list view with video player. So the first visible item in the list will be playing a video and the rest of the items in the list view will show a thumbnail.

When the user scrolls the list then I have to stop the last video playing item and need to start the video playing with the new current first visible item in the list like youtube.

My code is working but when I am scrolling 2-3 times then it throws exceptions which are given below.

```
2022-06-21 09:52:17.363 4846-9547/com.indiadotcom.zeekannada E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, 1203418, null, [852, 480, -1.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:555)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, 1203418, null, [852, 480, -1.0], [-1, -1])
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1051)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:606)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1465)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:713)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:998)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:830)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:945)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
     Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, error 0xfffffff4
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1924)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1858)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createCodec(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:73)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:48)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1137)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1044)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:606) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1465) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:713) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:998) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:830) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:945) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:478) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
2022-06-21 09:52:17.376 4846-4976/com.indiadotcom.zeekannada E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, 1203418, null, [852, 480, -1.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)
```

Video player controller - 2.4.0

**ListView Code**

```
Widget buildList(SectionModal modal) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
          if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
            debugPrint("Scroll Start");
            scrollStart = true;
            // setState(() {
            //   message = "Scroll Start";
            // });
          } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            debugPrint("Scroll Update");
            // setState(() {
            //   message = "Scroll Update";
            // });
          } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
            debugPrint("Scroll End");
            scrollEnd = true;
            // setState(() {
            //   message = "Scroll End";
            // });
          }
          return false;
        },
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
          controller: autoScrollController,
          children: List.generate(modal.latestNews.length, (index) {
            //final index = data[0];
            //final height = data[1];
            return AutoScrollTag(
              key: ValueKey(index),
              controller: autoScrollController,
              index: index,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: VideoWidget(
                  modal.latestNews[index],
                  index,
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  _controller?.pause();

                  await Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          VideoDetail(
                            modal.latestNews,
                            index,
                          ),
                    ),
                  );
                  if (playingIndex == firstVisibleIndex) {
                    _controller?.play();
                  }
                },
              ),
              highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
  }
```

**Video Widget**

```
 Widget VideoWidget(NewsCommon? item, int i) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Column(children: [
          ClipRRect(
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                    return _playVideoView(item, i);
                  }),

                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 20,
                        right: 10,
                        left: 10,
                        top: 10,
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 5,
                        right: 10,
                        left: 10,
                        top: 5,
                      ),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                        color: const Color(0xccD32F2F),
                      ),
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          children: [
                            const WidgetSpan(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.play_arrow_outlined,
                                size: 20,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: ' ${getPlayTime(item?.playTime)}',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  if (playingIndex == i)
                    StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                      return Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              onMute = !onMute;
                              if (onMute) {
                                _controller?.setVolume(0);
                              } else {
                                _controller?.setVolume(1.0);
                              }
                              setState(() {});
                              //playingIndex = 6;
                              //_scrollToIndex();
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 20,
                                right: 10,
                                left: 10,
                                top: 10,
                              ),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 5,
                                right: 10,
                                left: 10,
                                top: 5,
                              ),
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                                color: const Color(0xe6000000),
                              ),
                              child: RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(
                                  children: [
                                    WidgetSpan(
                                      child: Icon(
                                        onMute
                                            ? Icons.volume_mute
                                            : Icons.volume_down_rounded,
                                        size: 20,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: onMute ? " UNMUTE" : "MUTE",
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ));
                    }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 10,
              right: 10,
              left: 10,
              top: 10,
            ),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: Text(
              item?.title ?? '',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Video Player and thumnail view**

```
 Widget _playVideoView(item, index) {
    bool isPlaying = false;
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
      _controller?.addListener(() {
        if (_controller!.value.isPlaying && !isPlaying) {
          isPlaying = true;
          setState(() {
            debugPrint(
                "_controller.value.isPlaying: ${_controller!.value.isPlaying}");
          });
        }
      });

      if (index == playingIndex &&
          _controller != null &&
          _controller!.value.isPlaying /*&& _controller.value.isInitialized*/) {
        //print(" If index: ${index}");
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
        );
      } else {
        //print(" Else index: ${index}");

        return CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: item.thumbnailUrl ?? '',
          placeholder: (context, url) =>
              Image.asset(
                defaultKannadaBig,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
              Image.asset(
                defaultKannadaBig,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: try `visibility_detector` package wrap videoPlayer with VisibilityDetector it fire  callback when the widget's visibility changes